# Do prescription swimming goggles have a gap between the lens and the goggles?

Tags: optics, lenses, vision

The lens-maker's equation for a given biconvex lens assumes that the refractive index of the medium either side of the lens is the same.
But in the case of prescription swimming goggles, this wouldn't be the case. On one side there will be water and on the other side (the inside of the goggles) there will be air to allow the eye to work correctly.

So does that mean the lens is separate to the goggles and just attached onto the front, such that there will be a gap between the two into which water can flow to allow the lens to work correctly, after which the light will enter the goggles and refract uniformly? I've googled pictures of prescription goggles but it's hard to tell from a sea of stock images!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a prescription snorkeling mask. It uses planoconcave lenses with the flat side bonded to the flat window of a normal mask.

This works for distant objects because parallel rays incident on a flat interface emerge as parallel rays. For nearer objects, there's a focus shift, but except for reading glasses, eyeglasses are usually optimized for distance vision.

Comment: My “prescription” racing goggles (Speedo brand) are just one piece molded plastic lenses. You buy the optometer you need (so not really prescription, more like the reading glasses in the drug store). No astigmatism or anything else.